# how to insert values in mysql database

Tags: mysql, jsp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEjIV.png)please any one help...
am using jsp with mysql database,Its an isa relation type,I have created a table named product which has a "product_id" as the primary key, and also I have created two other tables named "spare_parts" and "accessories" which doesn't has the primary key but have foreign key of product table.
now depending on form submission I want to insert my data in either of the tables.
please help

Comment: I would recommend adding a table schema to this question to get valuable answers.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable I see nothing impossible about it. But I agree that more details are needed.

Comment: ok if I give primary keys to those tables then how to proceed?

Comment: @uag001 read some tutorial or something, try to write some code and then if it does not work, ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

As per tutorial:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0360__JSP/Insertdatatoatable.htm

Use the query as:

```
INSERT INTO Product(ID, Name, brand, quantity) VALUES (....)

INSERT INTO SpareParts(ProductID, weight) VALUES (...)

INSERT INTO Accessories(ProductID, color) VALUES (....)
```

You should merge SpareParts and Accessories table if no other fields are needed.